# ¿Cómo puedo pasar por referencia una variable en C?

Tags: c

```
funcion1(){

}
funcion2(int *x){

    funcion1(le envio x)
}
int main(){
  int x;
  funcion2(&x);
}
```

cómo puedo pasar por referencia una variable desde una función a otra, siendo que a la primera función ya había llegado por referencia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primero, declara `funcion1` para recibir un puntero.

Luego, dentro de `funcion2`, ya tienes un puntero, así que simplemente lo pasas a función 1.

Mira este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x;
  funcion2(&x);
  printf("Hello World %d", x);
  return 0;
}

funcion2(int *x){
    *x = 2;
    funcion1(x);
}

funcion1(int *x){
    *x = *x + 3;
}
```

Que produce esta salida:

```
Hello World 5
```